# Change all pixels of a particular color in an (animated) gif?

Tags: animation, colors, gif

Change a color value of an animated gif : how to ?

I tried with Photoshop CC which allows changing colors of an individual palette, but does not allow changing the color in multiple layers. Only one layer at a tome.
And cannot find an option in Imagemagick as well.

A command like

convert  ~/Pictures/animgif/3d\ polyhedra/4P4Q.gif  -fill "#201940" -opaque "#000000" q.gif

does not work (#201940 is the color of the background which I want to change to black).

Looking up on the internet did not result in a solution.

```
convert  ~/Pictures/animgif/3d\ polyhedra/4P4Q.gif  -fill "#201940" -opaque "#000000" q.gif

I expect the backgroud color to be black.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have your ImageMagick command syntax backwards. -fill is the new color and opaque is the old color. So

```
convert ~/Pictures/animgif/3d\ polyhedra/4P4Q.gif -fill "#000000" -opaque "#201940" q.gif
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that works !
I used imagemagick with a wrong command line.